# Slim working on local but not live; namespace related?

Tags: php, namespaces, slim

I'm working [TextPress](https://github.com/shameerc/TextPress) (flat file blogging system) which runs on [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/).

It works without a hitch on my local server running php 5.4.4, but when I deploy to live server running php 5.3.10 I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Slim\Environment' 
    not found in /home/webstart/public_html/codagogy.com/blog/Slim/Slim.php 
    on line 180
```

([source of Slim.php](https://github.com/shameerc/TextPress/blob/master/Slim/Slim.php))

The point in the Slim class where it's failing is the first time it attempts to use the "Slim" namespace, so it leads me to believe there's an issue with the live server and namespaces.

According to the docs, namespaces should be supported as of php 5.3.

Is there some other server related configuration that could causing namespace use to fail?

Comment: What Operating Systems are the 2 servers?

Comment: Live: CENTOS 5.8 x86_64, Local: latest MAMP Pro

Comment: That was what I suspected. OSXs file system is case insensitive, but the CentOS one is (most likely) not. So, it's possible you have a directory that has the wrong case and the autoloader is failing to find the correct files.

Comment: Turns out I was barking up the wrong tree. I thought there was a problem with the autoloading / namespace that caused Environment to not be found. Turns out it couldn't be found because it *didn't exist*...The file name "Environment.php" was in my git ignore file for another reason, so it never got uploaded to live. Given I was using git to mirror the project I didn't think to check for the file not actually existing. What does one do with a post where the answer ends up being too localized? Close? Delete?

Answer (score 0):

I know Susan explained it was a .gitignore thing in this particular case (see question comments). 
**But** I'd like to copy/paste answer from @Brenton Alker which is super relevant to a local OS X (MAMP) and a live Linux setup:

> OSXs file system is case insensitive, but the CentOS one is (most
>   likely) not. So, it's possible you have a directory that has the wrong
>   case and the autoloader is failing to find the correct files.

Happened to me twice in this sprint alone. I thought this may help others who will google "namespace working on localhost, not live" like me.